# How to Show the Property Values in <input> text fields While Update in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I am Working on a User details form. i am registering in the user form and it is storing in the database.

Now I want to Update the user details Within same form.When i am getting the User Object from DB to Jsp, The data is not showing in Textfields.

How can i achieve this behavior.
My Sample Code is :

```
<form:form commandName="user" action="saveuser">
    <form:input path="userName" placeholder="name"/>
</form:form>
```

My Controller code is :

```
@Controller
public UserController{
   @Reqmap........
   public String getUserDetails(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,Map<Strig,Object> model) {
        List<User> listUser = some service.getDetails();
        //My 1st way
        model.put("user",listUser);
        //My 2nd Way 
       user = listUser.get(0);

       //above two ways are not worked
       return "userform";

   }
}
```

Comment: Any error exception ?

Comment: No. it is displaying form with place holders only

Comment: first take this line user = listUser.get(0); and then model.put("user",listUser); later on use modelAttribute="user" in <form:form> tag

Answer (score 2):

you don't have the `value` attribute set for your input. Try

```
<form:input path="userName" placeholder="name" value="${user.userName}"/>
```

It will work if you pass the `user` in the Model.

**edit:** I add the controller part

```
@RequestMapping(value="/your/url", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEditForm(Model model)
{
    User myUser = retrieveUserSomehow() //this obj must be a user. If you load a list, you should get the proper user entry. Of course, check that it's not null as well, but this is trivial, right?
    model.addAttribute("user", myUser);
    return "yourViewName";
}
```

here's the jsp

```
<form:form commandName="user" action="/your/url">
    <form:input path="userName" placeholder="name" value="${user.userName}"/>
</form:form>
```

this will work, provided that the `User` class has a `userName` attribute.

Comment: please, tell me how you populate the model. If you use your first approach you're going to pass a list not a user. You need to be aware of what you're using. I suggest you to do the following: `User myUser = loadUserSomehow();` then add the user to the model `model.addAttribute("user", myUser);`

Comment: I added some details to my previous answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Edit from @MaVVamaldo  is exactly what I was referring to in my answer.

Comment: @JsingH actually I can't understand why we've been downvoted. The answers make perfectly sense and solve the question.

Comment: That is true. I've been using this technique at so many places in my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want User object to populate value from DB to jsp on form load, then you need to set that value in your controller. for e.g. make sure User.name as some value. Then use User.name binding with a form attribute.